# Show that a measure $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite

Tags: measure-theory

I have the following exercise.

Let $(\mathit X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space. Show that the measure $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, if there exists a function $f \in \mathcal M^+(\mathit X)$ with $f(x) \gt 0$ for all $x \in \mathit X$ and $\int_{\mathit X} f d\mu \lt \infty $.

From what I understand is that the function $f$ has to be from the set $\mathcal M^+$, so the set of strictly positive numeric functions (as defined in the script of the professor).

Comment: "Numeric functions"? I have not seen this in my study of measure theory

Comment: Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence of nonnegative (finite) real numbers. Show that there exists $x_n>0$ and $\sum_n a_n x_n<\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_n = f^{-1}([n^{-1}, \infty])$. We have $n^{-1}\mu(A_n) \leq \int_{A_n} f < \infty$ and $\bigcup_{n} A_n = X$.

Comment: Hey MathematicsStudent1122, could you maybe explain this a little bit more? Unfortunately I don't understand it..